# Game/animation mockup/prototype tool

Tags: animation, 2d, prototyping, 2d-games, mockup-tool

Advanced mockup/prototype tool that can be used for game/animation prototyping wanted.

I need to add my images, then scale, rotate, screw, move them, and then get all the parameters: coordinates, angels, scale %.

All mockups that I've seen don't allow this. Adobe Flash Professional canvas is an 'ideal' candidate, but it has unacceptable price for such tool.

Mac preferred, but Win is OK.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Construct2 is really really good, and completely free.
https://www.scirra.com/construct2

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these :
[GameMaker](http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker/studio/free), offers Free and advanced features.

[Flixel](http://www.flixel.org/), open-source and free, based on ActionScript 3.